# How to map key-values in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm translating a java object to `JasperReports` for PDF templating.

I want to map a string, and depending on its value value map to a text representation. Like:

```
one=this is one string
two=this is two string
three=this is three string
...
```

How can I add some kind of keyvalue map inside jasper reports, so that I can read the property from the java object and map it inside jasper?

Answer (score 1):

JasperReport always receive a Map as Input Parameter. In such map you can put anything you want, even another map that meets your needs...

So, you have two ways to reach your goals:

One, is to build your own map and put it inside the map which jasper report take as input argument... Then, inside your jasper report, define a parameter of java.util.Map type and name it exactly as the key that maps your map inside the jasper report input parameters map (let's suppose that your map was called MY_MAP).

Later, when you need to retrieve a value from MY_MAP, use the expression `$P{MY_MAP}.get(<theKeyToBeTransaled>)`

The other option is to load a ResourceBundle and passed it to the report using the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter#REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE` key... Then, inside the report, use the built-in expression: `str(<theKeyToBeTransaled>)`

Hope this help...